# How to separate data extracted from the table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I extracted data from a database and sorted it based on the id. Now i need to separate out the rows with different ids. The aim is to find out the total price for each id and the latest date.

```
b_id    price date
----    ----------------
 1      98.30 2014-05-14
 1      65.70 2014-05-07
 2      14.40 2014-05-06
 2      55.60 2014-05-07
 2      38.20 2014-04-06
 3      84.40 2014-04-02
 3      31.30 2014-04-12
 3      74.40 2014-05-06
```

I tried to separate it using -

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    if($row['b_id'] == 1){


    }

}
```

But i cannot hard code it. How can i separate out the rows? Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Would it be better to do this directly on the query instead of the php code?

Comment: Try `SELECT SUM(b_id) FROM tablename WHERE b_id=1 AND date='your_pick'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want rigth on your query. It would be like:

```
select b_id, max(date) as maxdate, sum(price) total
  from your table
 group by b_id
 order by b_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL to achieve your goal. It's usually faster when the database handles simple calculations:

```
SELECT b_id,
 SUM(price) AS 'Price', 
 MAX(date)  AS 'Date'
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY b_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total price, your extraction could be

```
SELECT b_id, SUM( price) AS total_price FROM your_table GROUP BY b_id

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    echo "Id : " . $row['b_id'] . " Price : " . $row['total_price'];
}
```